# Can't add rows to table in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component.   In a useEffect I'm trying to create a new row and add the row to the table.  I tried using `insertRow`, but that didn't work either.  The element does exist and I am able to add a `mousedown` listener to it.

```js
const createRow = () => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(td);
  }
  return row;
};
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (id !== "-1") {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    element?.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      console.log("here");
    });

    const row = createRow();
    element?.append(row); // also tried appendChild
   // yes there should be a removeEventListener, but this is just to debug
  }
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createRow` function is working fine the problem is that you are creating three `td` and appending them to the created `tr` but those `td` are empty so the function is returning this :

```html
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

It is a table row with three empty table data, that's why it can't be observed, so with the same logic you have to append text to your `td`:

```js
const createRow = () => {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
       // add these two lines
      const content = document.createTextNode("Test");
      td.appendChild(content);
      row.appendChild(td);
    }
    return row;
  };
```

This will retun:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
```

**Note:** This is vanilla Javascript, if you are using react, it is recommanded to use refs to manipulate DOM elements instead of getting them by id